# SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator

Tags: pandas

The code was working with old version of Pandas, i have upgraded to 0.24.0 version, then its failing with Syntax error.

**Code:**

```
pandas_df = pd.read_excel(s3_src_file, usecols=range(int(start_range), int(end_range)), skiprows=1).dropna(how='all')
```

**log error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ndf_digital_weekly_budget_src_raw.py", line 191, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "ndf_digital_weekly_budget_src_raw.py", line 181, in main
    reject_bucket_prefix, raw_hive_table_path, budget_year, xls_read_ranges, weekly_budget_skip_rows)
  File "ndf_digital_weekly_budget_src_raw.py", line 77, in read_weekly_budget_file
    pandas_df = pd.read_excel(s3_src_file, usecols=list(range(int(start_range), int(end_range))), skiprows=weekly_budget_skip_rows).dropna(how='all')
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 350, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 653, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 405, in __init__
    filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 212, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    from pandas.io import s3
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/s3.py", line 5, in <module>
    import s3fs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fsspec import AbstractFileSystem
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fsspec/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spec import AbstractFileSystem
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 352
    yield path, dirs, files
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change `range` to `list`:

```
usecols=range(int(start_range), int(end_range))
```

to:

```
usecols=list(range(int(start_range), int(end_range)))
```

Reason is if check parameter `usecols` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> usecols : **list-like** or callable, optional

Comment: is the API changed? or something else? could you please explain more?

Comment: no it was working before.. and even after the changes you suggested, its throwing same error.

Comment: @Shankar - Can you test `print(list(range(int(start_range), int(end_range))))` ?

Comment: the print is working.. the above code is inside a function where i'm not returning anything.. its a void function... i think the error is something to do with return

Comment: i have updated the question with error log.. i think it is something to do with Python version and return statement..

Comment: @Shankar - And if test `print(s3_src_file)` it return correct value?

Comment: its returns correct value, because the file exist in s3

Comment: @Shankar - hmm, then no idea :(

Comment: the same code works in my PyCharm ID.. i think this is something to do with return and other lines in the function.. anyway.. thanks